# Warning in cd_core_log due to cd_storage_conf

Tags: 2011, content-delivery

I am working on a project of upgrading an existing tridion project to 2011 SP1 from 5.3. The entries in the cd_storage_conf are

```
<Item typeMapping="BinaryMeta" cached="true" storageId="defaultdb" />
      <Item typeMapping="BinaryVariant" cached="true" storageId="defaultdb" />
      <Item typeMapping="ComponentMeta" cached="true" storageId="defaultdb" />
      <Item typeMapping="ComponentPresentation" itemExtension=".Asp" storageId="defaultdb" />
      <Item typeMapping="ComponentPresentation" itemExtension=".Jsp" storageId="defaultdb" />
      <Item typeMapping="ComponentPresentation" itemExtension=".Xml" storageId="defaultdb" />
      <Item typeMapping="ComponentPresentation" itemExtension=".Txt" storageId="defaultdb" />
      <Item typeMapping="ComponentPresentationMeta" cached="true" storageId="defaultdb" />
       <Item typeMapping="Reference" storageId="defaultdb" />
      <Item typeMapping="ItemMeta" cached="true" storageId="defaultdb" />
      <Item typeMapping="DynamicLinkInfo" storageId="defaultdb" />
      <Item typeMapping="LinkInfo" cached="true" storageId="defaultdb" />
      <Item typeMapping="PageMeta" cached="true" storageId="defaultdb" /> 
      <Item typeMapping="XSLT" cached="true" storageId="defaultFile" />
      <Item typeMapping="Binary" itemExtension=".css" storageId="defaultFile" cached="true"/>
      <Item typeMapping="Binary" itemExtension=".swf" storageId="defaultFile" cached="true"/>
      <Item typeMapping="Binary" itemExtension=".js" storageId="defaultFile" cached="true"/>
      <Item typeMapping="Binary" itemExtension=".bmp" storageId="defaultFile" cached="true"/>
      <Item typeMapping="Binary" itemExtension=".png" storageId="defaultFile" cached="true"/>
      <Item typeMapping="Binary" itemExtension=".jpeg" storageId="defaultFile" cached="true"/>
      <Item typeMapping="Binary" itemExtension=".jpg" storageId="defaultFile" cached="true"/>
      <Item typeMapping="Binary" itemExtension=".gif" storageId="defaultFile" cached="true"/>
      <Item typeMapping="Binary" itemExtension=".pdf" storageId="defaultFile" cached="true"/>
      <Item typeMapping="Binary" itemExtension=".doc" storageId="defaultFile" cached="true"/>
      <Item typeMapping="Binary" itemExtension=".xls" storageId="defaultFile" cached="true"/>
      <Item typeMapping="Binary" itemExtension=".ico" storageId="defaultFile" cached="true"/>
      <Item typeMapping="Page" cached="true" storageId="defaultdb"/>
       <Item typeMapping="Metadata" cached="true" storageId="defaultdb"/>
       <Item typeMapping="XML" cached="true" storageId="defaultdb" />
```

In the log file, I am getting warnings related to certain items as below

```
2013-06-12 06:58:37,492 WARN  ConfigurationMetadataCheckLoader - Type mapping: 'BinaryVariant' for storage: defaultdb was found, typeMapping should be 'Metadata'
2013-06-12 06:58:37,501 WARN  ConfigurationMetadataCheckLoader - Type mapping: 'BinaryMeta' for storage: defaultdb was found, typeMapping should be 'Metadata'
2013-06-12 06:58:37,502 WARN  ConfigurationMetadataCheckLoader - Type mapping: 'ComponentMeta' for storage: defaultdb was found, typeMapping should be 'Metadata'
2013-06-12 06:58:37,502 WARN  ConfigurationMetadataCheckLoader - Type mapping: 'ComponentPresentationMeta' for storage: defaultdb was found, typeMapping should be 'Metadata'
2013-06-12 06:58:37,502 WARN  ConfigurationMetadataCheckLoader - Type mapping: 'ItemMeta' for storage: defaultdb was found, typeMapping should be 'Metadata'
2013-06-12 06:58:37,502 WARN  ConfigurationMetadataCheckLoader - Type mapping: 'PageMeta' for storage: defaultdb was found, typeMapping should be 'Metadata'
2013-06-12 06:58:37,502 WARN  ConfigurationMetadataCheckLoader - Type mapping: 'Publication' for storage: defaultdb was found, typeMapping should be 'Metadata'
2013-06-12 06:58:37,502 WARN  ConfigurationMetadataCheckLoader - Type mapping: 'Reference' for storage: defaultdb was found, typeMapping should be 'Metadata'
2013-06-12 06:58:37,502 WARN  ConfigurationMetadataCheckLoader - Type mapping: 'Schema' for storage: defaultdb was found, typeMapping should be 'Metadata'
2013-06-12 06:58:37,502 WARN  ConfigurationMetadataCheckLoader - Type mapping: 'LinkInfo' for storage: defaultdb was found, typeMapping should be 'Metadata'
```

Is it because the meta by default is stored in database and these items need to be explicitly mentioned only if the items need to be stored in file system. Beside this i am not able to understand why it is giving error for component presentation. In the documentation only the following type mapping are given for an item type
Binary,ComponentLinkClick,ComponentPresentation,ComponentVisit,DynamicLinkInfo,Metadata,Page,Personalization,Publication,Query,Taxonomy,Timeframe,TrackedPage,XSLT

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you just took your broker config and tried to manually copy the old bindings into new Item Type Mappings. This is not the right way to do it. There is an XSLT to automatically do the conversion, or you need to do it manually - the list you gave from the documentation is the list of allowed ItemType mappings, so that is why you see errors for the items you created that are not on that list.

A few pointers:

1. You do not need to specify a mapping for each item type. Items will go by default to the default storage specified on the ItemTypes element

```xml
<ItemTypes defaultStorageId="defaultDataFile" cached="false">
```

1. You do not have explicitly different metadata 'bindings' (what are now called Item Type Mappings) for the different types of metadata - you just use the `Metadata` Item Type for all.
2. You do not need to specify a `Binary` item type mapping for each file extension, unless you want them all to go to different storages. Similary for `ComponentPresentation`

Comment: Thanks Will,Yes you are correct we copied the broker config items manually. That solved my query, but can there be any scenario(just for example) where the page meta need to go to different storage and binary meta to different storage. Beside this publication is an allowed item type but its giving the same warning for publication as well.

Comment: I have never encountered a scenario where we wanted meta for different types in different storages. I think it may be a documentation defect that publication is an allowed item type, as I dont see it in the cd_storage_conf.xml example, and I guess that publication information is stored using the Metadata item type.